# postgres fdw create foreign table without specifiy columns

Tags: postgresql, oracle-fdw

need to create couple of foreign tables with a lot of columns from oracle.
I dont want to specify all cloumns by myself.
Is there a way to do something like this:

```
create foreign table ALFSTK **(*)** SERVER server1 options (schema 'test', table 'ALFSTK');
```

Or is this not possible with fdw?

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: postgresql_fdw doesn't talk to Oracle in the first place.  What are you actually using?

Comment: i use the oracle_fdw extension

Answer (score 1):

This is what [IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-importforeignschema.html) is for.  You can run it for a single table at a time if you want to.

[oracle_fdw](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw) says it supports IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA, but be sure to read that section of the docs for more info.

Comment: thanks for this advice. I also tried this... get message "import foreign schema" but no table is importet. \dt shows no relations. My command: "import foreign schema "GISRO" limit to (LASTEN) from server server1 into cabs;

Comment: That should work fine. Hard to tell what went wrong without knowing your schema.